# On-the-fly decoding HTTP bodies on Linux?

Tags: http, tcp, network-monitoring, http-headers, tcpdump

My wish is to monitor HTTP exchanges between my server and a browser. At present time, I use the localhost because I'm developping the app. I installed and used *tcpflow* and found it quite useful but the body of the response is encrypted (no https, I beleive it is gzipped if I refer to the header). Here is the exchange from `tcpflow -i lo -c -e`:

```
127.000.000.001.59549-127.000.000.001.00080: GET /dom/test.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4


127.000.000.001.00080-127.000.000.001.59549: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 05 Oct 2015 03:44:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Mon, 05 Oct 2015 03:06:42 GMT
ETag: "36031e-8e-52152cd86200d"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 118
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

...........Qt.w....qU.(......Q..)v\

6..%.
...E..%.J.%i..J.`.....T;....|......E.}....>D.MR~J%Xq.!.J..P.D....
.r..0....
```

And here is the *HTML* code:

```
<!DOCSTYLE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

What I would like to see as *response* is rather:

```
...
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 118
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCSTYLE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess the header entries `Vary: Accept-Encoding` and `Content-Encoding: gzip` are the source of my problem. Is there any way to get rid of this scrambling and see the *HTML* code in clear? I mean a rather easy way? Actually, I will have no control over the browser that requests with `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch`. *But for debug purposes, if the only way is the set the browser to request no Encoding/Compression, I can live with that.*

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Content encoded with `Content-Encoding: gzip` can be easily decompressed with piping the content through `gzip -d`. For deflate I don't know an utility but it can be done with some zlib programming. SDCH is no that easy because to decompress it you would need have access to the dictionary used for compression, which might be somewhere else in your packet capture or nowhere.

Gzip and probably deflate too should be transparently handled by wireshark, so that you can see the decoded headers there. An the httpflow tool coming with the [Net::Inspect](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-Inspect) perl package can also decode the gzip and deflate payload for you and can also be used to extract HTTP requests/response pairs from a pcap file and save each of these pairs as single pcap file with payload already decoded.

Comment: Hello! Actually I would like to decode the gzipped body on the fly. tcpflow displays dots for unprintable characters, I cannot pipe this directly to gzip. The gzip solution works fine however if I edit the file and remove the headers. ANyway... I'll find something else.